# Postgres: Alternative to IN and NOT IN

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following situation:
Category and Product tables with m-m relation, with a product_category table in between.

Question:
How can I retrieve products that are in a category with a value or not in the category at all?

```
Category
_________
category_id, category_type, category_value

Product
________
product_id

product_category
_____________
product_category_id, product_id, category_id
```

I wrote the query:

```
select product_id 
from product_category
where (
  (
  product_id IN 
    (
    select product_id 
    from product_category pc 
    join category c on pc.category_id = c.category_id 
      and category_type = 'type1' and category_value = 'v1'
    ) or product_id NOT IN (
    select product_id 
    from product_category pc 
    join category c on pc.category_id = c.category_id 
      and category_type = 'type1'
    )
  ) and (
  product_id IN (
    select product_id 
    from product_category pc 
    join category c on pc.category_id = c.category_id 
      and category_type = 'type2' and category_value = 'v2'
    ) or product_id NOT IN (
    select product_id 
    from product_category pc 
    join category c on pc.category_id = c.category_id 
    and category_type = 'type2'
    )
  )
)
```

While the above query works, the problem is the above query is inefficient for large tables and even the internet suggests to not use IN and NOT IN for large volumes of data.

So far I am unable to find an alternative.

### Edit:

Adding an example:

```
| Product    |
| product_id |
| p1         |
| p2         |

| Category                            |
| id | category_type | category_value | 
| 1  | type1         | v1             |
| 2  | type1         | v2             |
| 3  | type2         | c1             |
| 4  | type2         | c2             |

| product_category         |
| product_id | category_id |
| p1         | 1           | type1 v1
| p1         | 2           | type1 v2
| p1         | 3           | type2 c1
| p2         | 4           | type2 c2
```

When I request the products that are valid for category_type **type1** and category_value **anything**, the product P2 should be returned also. Not having a connection to a category type makes it valid for that category type.

Comment: Could you please add an example?

Comment: Concerning this point: "the internet suggests to not use IN..." Could you please be more precise? Where did you get this information from? "The internet" suggests a lot of things. For a concrete solution you likely will need to show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Using EXPLAIN query results in a huge cost: "Finalize Aggregate  (cost=167842928056.48..167842928056.49 rows=1 width=8)"

Comment: So what does the detail of the EXPLAIN PLAN show? Is it doing full table scans that could be removed by appropriate indexing - for example? It might be helpful if you posted the full output from the EXPLAIN PLAN in your question. It might make your query faster if you use EXISTS rather than IN. Also, it would make your code easier to write/read (and may help performance) if you put the core of the sub-query that you repeat into a CTE

Comment: Instead of using IN, why not treat these as JOINs? Might give the optimizer more to work with.

Comment: @NickW, there is no PLAN option for [EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) in Postgres.

Comment: Read [Subquery Performance](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/subqueries-and-performance-in-postgresql/).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Explain Plan was used as a generic term common across most RDBMSs rather than an explicit Postgresql command I was expecting the questioner to run

Answer (score 0):

Extract out your variables into a CTE and use the `bool_or()` and `bool_and()` to apply your criteria.

Also, make sure there is an index on `category.category_id`.

```
with invars (search_type, search_value) as (
  values ('type1', 'v1'), ('type2', 'c2')
), product_category_types as (
  select pc.product_id, c.category_type,  
         bool_or(i.search_value = c.category_value) as match_flag
    from invars i
         join category c 
           on c.category_type = i.search_type
         join product_category pc
           on pc.category_id = c.category_id
   group by pc.product_id, c.category_type
)
select product_id, bool_and(match_flag) as matches
  from product_category_types
 group by product_id 
having bool_and(match_flag);
```

[Working example you can play with.](https://dbfiddle.uk/5t92tWr0)